What's the safest way to improve upon an existing network cable running next to AC power in underground PVC conduit?
Yes, I know! You shouldn't do that...
Here's the thing: it's already done. This is an existing underground PVC conduit that provides both AC power (two phase 120V) and network (via unshielded (!) cat 5e) from the house to a barn and other buildings adjacent to the barn (in US/Pennsylvania). It was installed quite a while ago, hasn't burned down the house, and works ok-ish (@100Mbps).
Also: this is an old house and a (probably) even older barn. There's knob and tube wiring in some places that's still in use! It's not my house, but it's family.
Right now they would like faster networking (there's cameras, online machinery, and an office). There's gigabit switches on both ends of the ~ 150' cat5e run, and sometimes they negotiate gigabit speeds initially, but then they throttle down to 100Mbit eventually. Not exactly a surprise, as the network cable is unshielded and running right next to AC power.
Installing an additional conduit is not really an option. The yard has been paved over since the conduit was installed. Getting rid of the network connection isn't going to happen either. They need it, and it works ok. So, either I help them upgrade the network and hopefully improve safety somewhat, or the existing solution remains in place.
We have a large spool of good quality cat6 network cable available. Individually shielded pairs + overall shield around all pairs + spline, rated for 550Mhz.
My options are:

use the cat6 cable available, make sure to ground it (on one end?). Lowest cost, should hopefully enable gigabit speeds, and should be somewhat safer / closer to code-ish.
use higher rated cable? Cat7/8? We'd just need to buy the cable, so not a huge cost. Would it enable higher bandwidth and/or be closer to code-ish?
run fiber instead? Probably safest / most code-ish solution? We don't have fiber cable though, nor do we have fiber capable switches. I've also never terminated a fiber cable, but we could get someone to do that part. Still an option, though more expensive.

Thoughts?

What's the diameter of the pvc conduit? What wires/cables are inside?

The more likely cause of poor speed is that it's full of water and isn't exterior rated cable. In any case, replacing it with fiber is the best option for a cable solution that's code compliant and also works better. But make sure it's exterior rated (wet) fiber cable, because all conduits are wet, and interior fiber also doesn't do so well when soaked for a few years.

Have you considered trying something like Nest/Google mesh for the hop? Or a traditional radio solution? I know this isn't what you asked about, but these are simple options.

Which electrical code applies in your location?  Also, is it really two-phase, or is it 110/220V single phase?

Point-to-point WiFi using directional antennas should get you a strong, stable signal over that sort of range.

Fiber is the only code compliant solution. You are not allowed to put SELV wires (like network cables) in a power conduit, but because fiber is electrically non-conductive it is allowed.
Alternatives are wireless networking and powerline networking. But if you need gigabit it may be tricky to get sufficient performance with these options.

SELV is an IEC term. OP is in NEC-land where Cat5e with 300V insulation is allowed (though usually avoided) in the same raceway with other circuits below that voltage. (Depending on local amendments.)

For this application you need to find both 300V and waterproof, because buried conduit is a wet location.

@Theodore -- no, it isn't allowed -- see NEC 800.133(A)(3) for the details

@ThreePhaseEel Ah! New in the 2023 NEC. Not adopted universally, but still a good idea to follow. I wonder what the listed barriers in Exception No. 1 look like. Innerduct?

@Theodore -- mixing wires/cables and innerducts in the same conduit produces a whole host of issues

@ThreePhaseEel I didn't say I'd recommend innerduct combined with loose wire. I only wondered what a listed barrier for raceway would be. (Listed barriers in boxes are common and well known.)

Before you start planning a pull through that old conduit you will need to check if it can still be pulled through, root intrusion might have clogged it.
There's a few more options you might not have considered yet:
A fourth option is to make a wireless bridge, take a paired set of directional wifi antennas and point them at each other.
The fifth option is to cut into the pavement and bury a second conduit and then patch the pavement again.
A sixth option is to suspend the network run above ground. Take a steel wire and some tall poles and create a run that way.
For a fiber run you can get a pre-terminated cable and you would only need a converter at each end not a full switch. That should bring the cost down to a few $100.

Thanks. I've considered wireless as well. Maybe something like a unifi Building Bridge? I guess it's an option but $500 isn't cheap and I wonder how finicky it will be over time? It gets windy here, and plenty of snow and bad weather in winter.
https://store.ui.com/us/en/products/ubb
Cutting open the pavement is not really an option.
Above ground could be an option... that's how power used to run before the conduit was put in. Wire sometimes got caught (and snapped) by trucks or farm equipment.
We'd prefer to stick to the conduit. So maybe fiber is the way?

Pre-terminated fibre would be my personal preference based on OP's description.   Add a powered FOT at each end and there's no need to change ethernet switching.    And Farmer can brag about how they're on fibre.

Most of the time a switch with at least one SFP (or XFP/SFP+ if you want to be all modern) cage (and more than one copper ethernet port) costs LESS than a "fiber converter" (which is a switch with two ports - one fiber, one copper) so don't jump to "use a converter" before shopping around.

Fiber is the obvious answer, both from future-proof perspective and the voltage isolation. It also protects the equipment from induced voltages from lightning strikes, which can be an issue in long wire runs.
Media converters between Ethernet RJ45 and fiber are readily available.
Pre-terminated fiber cable is available with a pull loop on one end, ordered to the length you need:

(Image source: Discount Low Voltage)
You would need enough space in the conduit to fit it through. This manufacturer recommends 1" diameter, so with the another cable already there, you'd probably want at least 1.5".
There is also a risk that the original conduit has collapsed under weight or tree roots have grown into it, in which case pulling any type of new cable is likely to fail. As you probably need to remove the old Cat5 cable to make space and to get a drawstring in, you run the risk of being left without any connection.

Split the current Cat5e connection
100 Mbit Ethernet only uses 2 pairs out of the 4 available in the Cat5e cable.
You can get two independent 100 Mbit connections through the currently installed cable. It would need separate switches at the far end, and you would connect some devices (such as the cameras) to one switch and the rest to the other switch.
This solution gives you twice the speed with minimal effort.
The code compliance issues will remain as they are. Having the switches at either end grounded will provide some protection, as Ethernet itself has isolation transformers at both ends.

Option 7, is powerline, or ethernet-over-power.
Personally I hate them and have a low success rate, though other people tell me my results are a-typical.
To improve the chance of success given you have one power backhaul, there would ideally be a power socket/outlet in the house and in the barn, on the same power circuit.
Then you have these modules plugged in, one in each building.

This provides you with effectively a replacement for your existing wire, with the signal "hetrodyned" or modulated on top of the 50/60hz AC wave form.
Large spikes in the power load could cause dropouts, so welders, large motors and other such huge startup current demands can affect throughput.
Best part, they're reasonably cheap and can be on-sold if they don't suit your requirements, to help fund the fibre that should have gone in originally.

STP or Shielded Twisted Pair might help too, but there's a cost and no guarantee it will help.   If you do go this way, remember to get shielded jacks for each end, and ground one end.
Cat 7/8 is a waste of money - the cat6 would be fine.  Even cat5 can carry gigabit.
Another consideration - if you're going to the effort to run one cable, run two or more for future proofing/channel bonding.
Also pull through some nylon string as a draw-cable for the next guy, which may be you.

in my experience these have always worked, but never better than wifi in an apartment. considering op wants gigabit, i'd steer away from them.

As far as cost/benefit goes, these will be OP's best option.  I support about 120 workers who all work from their homes and these are our go-to for folks for whom Ethernet cable is not an option (some are renters, etc).  I routinely get 1Gb/s FDx out of them, even in situations where the ends are on opposite legs of a service.  At roughly ~$35-70 for a set depending on brand, they're worth a shot.
